# How do you modify a string in C

Tags: c, string, reverse, c-strings

I'm new to C and I'm attempting to perform a modification to a string that I have (I'm attempting to reverse it), but I'm unsure why the program doesn't run as intended (displays no output).

```
void reverse(char *rTarget);

int main()
{
    char memes[] = "memes";
    reverse(memes);
    printf("%s", memes);
}

void reverse(char *rTarget)
{
    char swap;
    int length = (int) strlen(rTarget);

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        swap = rTarget[i];
        rTarget[i] = rTarget[length - i];
        rTarget[length - i] = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a pointer, because the `char* rTarget[]` expression means "an array of `char*`". You must pass the char array (it's basically also a pointer) then modify it. It will not be cloned.

Comment: First of all, your algorithm is wrong, you want to reverse the array so you shall iterate until the half of the array and swap with its equivalent in the second part, why do you iterate over the whole array?

Comment: @CoderCharmander Ah okay, didn't clock the char array is basically a pointer on its own. Thanks.

Comment: @AhmedSalah This isn't meant to be a correctly functioning piece of code, it was just a mockup because I wanted to now how I could actually pass and manipulate a string.

Comment: @AnimeCoder It is a bad idea that you changed your code after selecting the best answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow none of the answers are correct... the only element of the code changed was the for loop, to reflect the half-length search (clearing all logical errors).

Comment: @AnimeCoder You are mistaken. My answer is correct. And it is the only answer that shows how to write a correct function implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this function declaration

```
void reverse(char *rTarget[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void reverse(char **rTarget);
```

There is no great sense to declare it such a way.

You should declare the function like

```
void reverse( char rTarget[] );
```

and call it like

```
reverse( memes );
```

The function definition is also wrong. At least you have to use the loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
```

and these expressions

```
    swap = *rTarget[i];
    *rTarget[i] = *rTarget[length - i];
    *rTarget[length - i] = swap;
```

are invalid. They shall be rewritten like

```
    swap = ( *rTarget )[i];
    ( *rTarget )[i] = ( *rTarget )[length - i -1];
    ( *rTarget )[length - i - 1] = swap;
```

Also the variable `length` shall have the type `size_t` because in general an object of the type int can not accommodate an object of the type size_t and the function `strlen` have the return type `size_t`. So you have to substitute this declaration

```
int length = (int) strlen(*rTarget);
```

For this declaratiuon

```
size_t length = strlen(*rTarget);
```

Pay attention to that according to the conventions for standard C string functions the function should return pointer to the reversed string.

And according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be declared and defined

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char memes[] = "memes";

    puts( reverse( memes ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
semem
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
*rTarget[i] = *rTarget[length - i]
*rTarget[length - i] = swap;
```

The primary problem seems to be operator precedence. `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. You are passing "array of strings" (because pointers can be used as arrays), so when `i` is 0, on the left side you take the first (and only existing) array at `[0]`, and `*` references its first character. To this you assign nonsense from the right side: first character of array `[length]` (which doesn't exist), which is undefined behavior, so what you program does after this is meaningless to speculate about. You need to add parentheses, so that you reference the pointer to array, so you get the actual array, and then use `[]` on that.

But even if you add parentheses, your algorithm is wrong. On first round, `i` is 0 so you copy `(*rTarget)[length]` to start of string. That is the string terminating 0, so you end up with modified string length 0 (first byte is 0). You need -1 for the length.

Fixing your original code, it therefore becomes:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        swap = (*rTarget)[i];
        (*rTarget)[i] = (*rTarget)[length - i - 1];
        (*rTarget)[length - i - 1] = swap;
    }
```

---

Additionally, your function argument is needlessly complex (pointer to pointer to char), straight pointer to modifiable string is enough. Other answers cover that beauty issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *rTarget);

int main()
{
    char memes[] = "memes";
    reverse(memes);
    printf("%s", memes);
}

void reverse(char *rTarget)
{
    int length = (int) strlen(rTarget);

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        char swap = rTarget[i];
        rTarget[i] = rTarget[length - i - 1];
        rTarget[length - i - 1] = swap;
    }
}
```

The expression *rTarget[i] is parsed as *(rTarget + i), not *(rTarget) + i as you may expect. And you do not need to pass char ** here.

Answer (score -1):

There are all kinds of dereferencing errors here. Rememember, a string is an array of characters, not an array of character pointers. So this

```
void reverse(char *rTarget[])
```

Should be

```
void reverse(char rTarget[])
```

And here:

```
int length = (int) strlen(*rTarget);
```

You don't have to dereference `rTarget`, so remove the `*`. Same in the swap, remove all `*` that you have there.

Last but not least, there's an off by one error in your swap. Instead of going to `length - i`, you want to go to `length - i - 1`, otherwise you're swapping the null terminator to the beginning.

Also your loop should only go to the first half of the array, because otherwise you swap everything twice, resulting in the original string again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
```

All in all it should look like this:

```
void reverse(char rTarget[]);

int main()
{
    char memes[] = "memes";
    reverse(memes);
    printf("%s", memes);
}

void reverse(char rTarget[])
{
    char swap;
    int length = (int)strlen(rTarget);

    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        swap = rTarget[i];
        rTarget[i] = rTarget[length - i - 1];
        rTarget[length - i - 1] = swap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do it:

```
void reverse(char rTarget[]);

int main()
{
    char memes[] = "memes";
    reverse(memes);
    printf("%s", memes);
}

void reverse(char rTarget[])
{
    char swap;
    int lastindex = (int) strlen(rTarget) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < lastindex / 2; i++)
    {
        swap = rTarget[i];
        rTarget[i] = rTarget[lastindex - i];
        rTarget[lastindex - i] = swap;
    }
}
```

There are a couple of problems in your code.
First of all, arrays are always 'passed by reference', so you don't need to pass a pointer to an array. Any changes you make in the array will persist after the function call.
Secondly, array subscripts in C start from 0. So the last character (not counting null) in a string of length `n` is `string[n-1]` not `string[n]`.

EDIT: As @roottraveller mentioned, since you are swapping characters, you don't need to run till the end of the string. You only need to go till the half of length.

Comment: the for loop should run only half of length.

Comment: Ok, would any of the downvoters care to explain what is wrong?

Comment: `reverse(&memes);` - This should have at lease gave a warning when compiled

Comment: @EdHeal Fixed it (it did work so I kind of missed the warning)

Comment: Yes, array subscripts start from 0 ... Therefore: [0] = m, [1] = e, [2] = m, [3] = e, [4] = s. strlen(memes) = 5, hence if you increment from 0 to < 5, you increment up to and including 4...

Answer (score -3):

If you are not intended to send multiple strings to reverse function then function argument only require a char pointer. While swap character you need to traverse only 50% of the string. The code can be as following.

```
void reverse(char *rTarget)
{
    char swap;
    int length = (int) strlen(rTarget);
    for(int i = 0, j = (length - 1); i < (length / 2); i++, j--)
    {
        swap = *(rTarget+i);
        *(rTarget+i) = *(rTarget+j);
        *(rTarget+j) = swap;
    }
}
```